# wso2 esb 4.6.0 and Wso2 DSS 3.0.1 with xslt mediator

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Here  my services

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Getxslt"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence onError="fault">
         <xslt key="emptransform">

         </xslt>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <select xmlns=""/>
            </format>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/emp_DataService/" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence onError="fault">
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="serviceType">proxy</parameter>
</proxy>
```

XSLT  is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="emptransform">

      <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                      xmlns:ns1="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
                      version="1.0">
         <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
         <xsl:template match="ns1:Body">
            <ns1:select/>
         </xsl:template>
      </xsl:stylesheet>

   <description/>
</localEntry>
```

DSS Service :-
Dss:-

```
<data name="emp_DataService" serviceNamespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
   <config id="default">
      <property name="carbon_datasource_name">Signingtest</property>
   </config>
   <query id="select_all_emp_query" useConfig="default">
      <sql>SELECT eno, username, password FROM public.emp</sql>
      <result element="empCollection" rowName="emp">
         <element column="eno" name="eno" xsdType="xs:integer"/>
         <element column="username" name="username" xsdType="xs:string"/>
         <element column="password" name="password" xsdType="xs:string"/>
      </result>
   </query>>
   <operation name="select">
      <call-query href="select_all_emp_query"/>
   </operation>
  </data>
```

I am getting following error:-

XSLT in wso2 esb gives an error

```
{"ResponseJSON":{"Body":{"Data":{"Exception":"Unable to perform XSLT transformation using : Value {name ='null', keyValue ='emptransform'} against source XPath : s11:Body\/child::*[position()=1] | s12:Body\/child::*[position()=1]"}},"Status":"0"}}
```

i am using wso2 esb 4.6.0 and DSS 3.0.1 , i written proxy service that uses xslt mediator, when i am executing my proxy it gives the following error .
Could you please correct me, where did i mistake..

Answer (score 0):

What is the payload you are trying to send to the proxy ?  In your XSLT you match the BODY with the namespace "http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice", are you sending a payload which have that name space ? Apparently it is not. Best thing is, use a 3rd party online xslt evaluator and run our xslt against the request payload and verify your xslt behaves correctly prior to sending it through the ESB. That way it will be easy for you to isolate errors.